# Creating dynamic mysql queries

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to create sql file which can get two  number parameters and use them in a loop, that in each iteration we do replace into directive using the two parameters, and increment them at the end of the loop?

Can someone show me how to do so?

**Edit**: Consider I want to update table named zip code, I want to insert new codes in this way:
You get two parameters which are numbers.
The first is the a start code for example: 1000
The second is number of sequential codes to add , lets say 5.
So you will update the table with 1000, 1001... 1004

Comment: You need an actual example of what you want to do including data and output.

Comment: @Paul: added example

Comment: SQL is not a procedural language. You can use stored procedures which extend it with some control structures. Or you can "generate" data such that you can then select the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

SQL query cannot do loops, but you can "emulate" them by generating some data and then describing what you want to do with them in declarative way:

```
-- your input variables
set @start = 1000;
set @count = 5;

select val as zip from (
  -- generate some numbers starting with the value of @start
  select @start + (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) as val
    from (
      -- this creates cross join of 3 tables of numbers 0-9
      -- so the select up there gets rows with values 0-999
      -- you can add another cross join and 1000*d.a to get 0-9999
      select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
        cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
        cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
  ) tmp
-- we should generate enough numbers to always cover the needs
-- then this condition will filter only currently needed values
where (val >= @start) and (val < @start + @count)
```

See it at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/17037

I used this in few cases to generate all days between some dates (mostly to fill gaps in data for reporting) and it was surprisingly fast even if I tried big numbers. But if you know what the maximal value of @count can be, you can just use that much.